# paypal ipn simple question

Tags: php, paypal

I want to ask just a thing. I am using paypal for the first time. not by buttons. the data i sends through html page , is it returned by the ipn?

i am using a paypal class and this is my custom data:

```
 $this->paypal_class->add_field('cemail', $this->session->userdata('check_email'));
  $this->paypal_class->add_field('fname', $this->session->userdata('check_name'));
```

just wanna ask if it returned by the ipn or not.

Comment: If i remember well there's a transaction id that you must send to paypal, the transaction id is always returned so you can take data according to that if you save customers data before doing the request

Comment: is it the txn_id? is it not automatically generated by paypal? or i can set it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PayPal returns POST variables back to your notify_url via what they call IPN, its really just a callback to a url you specify either via your post to them or settings in you paypal account.

Paypal returns following variables to you, if you specify a notify_url;

- mc_gross
- invoice
- settle_amount
- protection_eligibility
- address_status
- payer_id
- tax
- address_street
- payment_date
- payment_status
- charset
- address_zip
- mc_shipping
- mc_handling
- first_name
- mc_fee
- address_country_code
- exchange_rate
- address_name
- notify_version
- settle_currency
- custom
- payer_status
- business
- address_country
- address_city
- verify_sign
- payer_email
- txn_id
- payment_type

**invoice** is returned if you set it. It can be used as your own order-id/transaction-id.

**txn_id** is generated by paypal and is their own id for the transaction.

If you add items yourself you will PayPal also returns **num_cart_items**, **item_name1** (item_name2, item_name3), **quantity1** (quantity2, quantity3) and such.

More reading at https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables